# Why Does VBA Programmatically Created ListBox.List Disappear when UserForm gets Loaded

Tags: excel, vba, userform, listboxitem

When programmatically creating and initializing a ListBox on a UserForm in Excel 365 64-bit, with the extensibility add-in reference set, everything starts out as expected; the ListBox is visible on the UserForm with ListBox.List items showing up in the ListBox sunken window and a scroll bar at the bottom.
[1. Form Before Load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mepNY.jpg)

However, as soon as the UserForm gets loaded using `VBA.UserForms.Add(myUserform.Name)`, the ListBox window becomes empty, and the scroll bar disappears.
[2. Form After Load, VBE View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msvON.jpg)
Even though it appears empty in the UserForm, ListBox.List still contains entries.

And, when Show is executed, the form appears the same.
[3. Form as Displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9FaHu.jpg)

Here is the minimum reproducible example VBA code:

```
Sub DisappearingListboxListMRE()
    Dim myUserform As VBComponent
    Dim lbxTest As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim UF As Object
    
    'Add a Userform
    Set myUserform = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    
    'Create ListBox on the form
    Set lbxTest = myUserform.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")

    'Initialize Listbox
    lbxTest.List = Split("Item 1;Item 2;Item 3", ";")
    
    'After code stops here, open UserForm1 in the VBE. Note that the ListBox
    'has three entries and scrollbars at the bottom. Then resume execution
    Stop
    
    
    'Load the form, but don't Show yet
    Set UF = VBA.UserForms.Add(myUserform.Name)
    
    'After code stops here, open UserForm1 in the VBE. Note that the ListBox
    'has NO visible entries and LACKS scrollbars at the bottom. Then resume execution
    Stop
    
    'Note that the UF as displayed also lacks entries and scrollbars
    UF.Show
    
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=myUserform
End Sub
```

Any suggestions?  The same thing happens with a ComboBox

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to add your list items within the userform initialize event handler...

```
Sub DisappearingListboxListMRE()
    Dim myUserform As VBIDE.VBComponent
    Dim lbxTest As MSForms.ListBox
    Dim UF As Object
    Dim strCode As String
    
    'Create the userform
    Set myUserform = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Add(vbext_ct_MSForm)
    
    'add a listbox
    Set lbxTest = myUserform.Designer.Controls.Add("Forms.ListBox.1")
    
    lbxTest.Name = "myListBox"
    
    'Build the string for the Userform Initialize event handler
    strCode = ""
    strCode = "Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()"
    strCode = strCode & vbCrLf & "    Me.Controls(""" & lbxTest.Name & """).List = Split(""Item 1;Item 2;Item 3"", "";"")"
    strCode = strCode & vbCrLf & "End Sub"

    'Add the Userform Initialize event handler
    With myUserform.CodeModule
        .InsertLines .CountOfDeclarationLines + 1, strCode
    End With
    
    'Load the form
    Set UF = VBA.UserForms.Add(myUserform.Name)
    
    UF.Show
    
    ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents.Remove VBComponent:=myUserform
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Aha!  Thanks.  Or, more conveniently, I can declare lbxList as Public, assign it the list array, then change the tird line of your event handler to

Comment: strCode = strCode & vbCrLf & "    Me.Controls(""" & lbxTest.Name & """).List = lbxList"

Comment: That answers it.  Thanks, Domenic!